# Повторная загрузка плагина

Tags: jquery, плагин

Использую в работе вот этот плагин: [`loupe | a jQuery image magnifier`](http://jdbartlett.com/loupe/)

Но есть проблема, изображения меняются динамически и лупа из-за этого немного бажит. Решением бы стало удаление текущей лупы и повторный вызов плагина. Но я не знаю как правильно удалить текущую лупу :(

Вот генерируемый код

```
<div class="loupe" id="loupe" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 220px; top: 319px; visibility: visible;"><img src="урл картинки скрыл" style="position: absolute; left: -313px; top: -424px;"></div>
```

Если использую remove() то див удалится, но плагин больше не загрузится. Можете подсказать что делать?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что правильным решением является удаление текущей лупы? Лучше не инициализировать её больше одного раза на изображении.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HappyCougar/ttyYU/show/ - Посмотрите, при инициации лупа появляется под курсором. Позже при прокрутке, она не успевает  ползти за курсором и остается где-то снизу. Двигать лупу к курсору через его координаты невозможно, так как это вызывает лютую ненавить лупы.

За одно можете прокоментировать мой индуский код.